# window function count aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, common-table-expression

I have two quite complex queries going on here. Both should return per given country (Netherlands in this case) the monthly use over the total of 12 months and the percentage that makes up that month of the total of those 12 months.

But the one where i use count as a windowing function returns one more row than the one where i don't use the count as a windowing function.

[image]

The query for the left side picture is:

```
;WITH MonthUsage AS
(
  SELECT customer_id, country_name, [Month], [Year], SUM(ItemsPerMonth) 
AS ItemsPerMonth
  FROM (
    SELECT cs.country_name, c.customer_id, YEAR(mol.date_watched) AS Year, MONTH(mol.date_watched) AS [Month], COUNT(*) AS ItemsPerMonth
    FROM Customer c
    JOIN Customer_Subscription CS ON C.customer_id = CS.customer_id
    JOIN Movie_Order_Line mol ON mol.customer_id = c.customer_id
    WHERE (mol.date_watched BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2018-07-01') AND cs.country_name = 'Nederland'
    GROUP BY c.customer_id,cs.country_name, YEAR(mol.date_watched), 
MONTH(mol.date_watched)

UNION ALL

SELECT cs.country_name, c.customer_id, YEAR(sol.date_watched) AS Year, 
MONTH(sol.date_watched), COUNT(*) AS ItemsPerMonth
      FROM Customer c
      JOIN Customer_Subscription CS ON C.customer_id = CS.customer_id
      JOIN Show_Order_Line sol ON sol.customer_id = c.customer_id
      WHERE sol.date_watched BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2018-07-01'
      GROUP BY c.customer_id, cs.country_name, YEAR(sol.date_watched), 
    MONTH(sol.date_watched)
) AS MonthItems
WHERE country_name = 'Nederland'
GROUP BY customer_id, country_name, [Month], [Year]
),
Months(MonthNumber) AS 
(
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MonthNumber + 1 
  FROM months
  WHERE MonthNumber < 12
)
SELECT cmb.[Year], ISNULL(cmb.[Month], m.MonthNumber) AS [Month], 
ISNULL(ItemsPerMonth, 0) AS ItemsPerMonth, 
ISNULL(FORMAT(((CAST(ItemsPerMonth AS decimal) / CAST((
    SELECT SUM(ItemsPerMonth) 
    FROM MonthUsage) AS decimal
))),'P0'), '0%') AS [PercentageOfTotal]
FROM MonthUsage cmb
JOIN Customer c ON c.customer_id = cmb.customer_id
JOIN Months m ON m.MonthNumber = cmb.[Month]
ORDER BY cmb.[Year] ASC, [Month] ASC
```

And the query for the right picture is:

```
;WITH MonthUsage AS (
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        YEAR(date_watched) AS [Year], 
        MONTH(date_watched) AS [Month], 
        COUNT(order_id) OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(YEAR(date_watched), MONTH(date_watched))) AS ItemsPerMonth
    FROM Movie_Order_Line mov
    JOIN Customer c ON c.customer_id = mov.customer_id
    JOIN Customer_Subscription cs ON C.customer_id = cs.customer_id
    WHERE date_watched BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2018-07-01' AND cs.country_name = 'Nederland'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT YEAR(date_watched) AS [Year], MONTH(date_watched) AS [Month], COUNT(order_id) OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(YEAR(date_watched), MONTH(date_watched))) AS ItemsPerMonth
    FROM Show_Order_Line sol
    JOIN Customer c ON c.customer_id = sol.customer_id
    JOIN Customer_Subscription cs ON C.customer_id = cs.customer_id
    WHERE date_watched BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2018-07-01' AND cs.country_name = 'Nederland'
) AS Combined
GROUP BY [YEAR], [Month], ItemsPerMonth
)
SELECT *, ISNULL(FORMAT(((CAST(ItemsPerMonth AS decimal) / CAST((SELECT 
SUM(ItemsPerMonth) FROM MonthUsage) AS decimal))),'P0'), '0%') AS 
[PercentageOfTotal]
FROM MonthUsage
ORDER BY [Year] ASC, [Month] ASC
```

I can't seem to figure out why i'm getting different results. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Looks like this line is to blame `GROUP BY [YEAR], [Month], ItemsPerMonth`

Comment: I see. But isn't it weird that it groups all the other rows correctly except the row of month 2 (see image above)?

Comment: It depends on data in the grouped table.

Comment: Remove the ItemsPerMonth from the GROUP BY in the cte from the query for the right one, and you should get the same results.